# Getting groups of a pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like

```
           "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?"
```

I also have a pattern like

```
             "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)"
```

Now according to the pattern, I think

group(0): "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?"

group(1): This order was placed for QT

group(2): 3000

group(3): ! OK?

If anything wrong here, please correct me

Thank You

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> group(0): "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?"

This is of course correct.

> group(1): This order was placed for QT

If you notice, the regex uses greedy quantifier `.*` before `\\d+`. The regex will therefore  match as much as it can, and will just leave a single digit for `\\d+` to match. `group(1)` will actually contain - `This order was placed for QT300`

> group(2): 3000

It will contain just the last `0`, and not `3000`.

> group(3): ! OK?

Correct.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to capture everything before digits then it is better to use `\D*` using this regex:

```
^(\\D*)(\\d+)(.*)$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/mE0mW7

Comment: nice one, I have not seen regex101 site before.

Comment: It is pretty handy for testing regex with many nice features like regex explanation and color coding.